# how to pass an array as argument in java (one line only)?

Tags: java, arrays, arguments

In ruby it would look like

```
myfunction (["element1", "element2", "element3"],"other argument")
```

Can I do the same in java? **One line only.**

I know I can use

```
        String[] dataToPass = new String[3];
        dataToPass[0] = "element1";
        dataToPass[1] = "element2";
        dataToPass[2] = "element3";
        myfunction(dataToPass,"other argument");
```

Comment: .. what is this I don't even...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
myfunction(new String[]{"e1", "e2", "e3"},"other argument");
```